# Caixa de pesquisa ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5

Estou com dúvidas nas criação de uma caixa de pesquisa de itens. Já adianto que sou iniciante.

Quero que quando o usuário digite um nome na caixa de pesquisa apareça os itens que contém o nome que o usuário digitou ou parte dele, por exemplo: o usuário digitou *materiais* ou *mat* então deveria aparecer:

- materiais de expediente
- materiais automotivos
- etc...

Minha maior dúvida é como implementar isso usando DDD. Vi este [exemplo](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), e achei relativamente simples, mas não imagino uma forma de implementação. Vi que ele implementa PagedList.Mvc e achei simples, mas como deixar desacoplado (Usando DDD)?

Um exemplo do que foi implementado lá

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
   ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
   ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
   ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

   if (searchString != null)
   {
      page = 1;
   }
   else
   {
      searchString = currentFilter;
   }

   ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

   var students = from s in db.Students
                  select s;
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
   {
      students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                             || s.FirstMidName.Contains(searchString));
   }
   switch (sortOrder)
   {
      case "name_desc":
         students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
         break;
      case "Date":
         students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
         break;
      case "date_desc":
         students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
         break;
      default:  // Name ascending 
         students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
         break;
   }

   int pageSize = 3;
   int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
   return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

No meu entender, há uma outra forma de fazer isto para deixar desacoplado.

Comment: Poderia postar seu código? Somente com isso fica difícil lhe ajudar.

Comment: @Randrade Estou só com o código do textbox pronto. Nada a mais.

Answer (score 0):

Existem dois itens a serem implementados para conseguir esse tipo de experiencia rica em buscas.

1. **[Typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)**

   Com esse componente você conseguirá criar essa experiencia de *autocomplete* ou *sugestions* durante a busca em seu aplicativo.
2. **[Search Engine](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/search/)**

   Voce pode desenvolver um backend para realizar as buscas, ou então usar algum serviço para fazer isso de uma forma mais performática, relevante e escalável. eu recomendo fortemente a usar o [Azure Search](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/search/) como plataforma de busca. É acessível e também muito fácil de implementar. Ele conta não apenas com serviço de **pesquisa**, mas também possui serviço de **sugestões** para fazer exatamante o que você precisa.

Em meu blog postei um curso, gratuito, com uma [Visão Geral do Azure Search](http://thiagolunardi.net/2015/12/mva-microsoft-azure-search/). Nele eu explico todas as principais *features* dessa Plataforma como Serviço e como consumila.

Lá também possui um código fonte para demonstração de também como usar cada um dos recursos. Desde como carregar dados para o serviço, até como usar o serviço de sugestões com pesquisas *fuzzy* - ex: vc pesquisa por "floers" e ele sugere "flores".

Comment: Bem interessante o que vc postou mas, para mim isso ainda é um pouco performático. Queria uma solução mais simples.

Comment: @tek6, basta vc mesmo criar seu backed para buscas. O Typeahead é super simples de implementar e usar. Mas ele deve ser "alimentado" de alguam maneira. Faça da maneira que vc souber fazer/achar mais fácil. Depois vc "evolui" essa solução.